# ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> with a ReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, c#-8.0

I have a bunch of classes that need to return properties as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`s, which works well when they're just `List<T>`s, however, things get really sloppy with than list is inside a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

================================================

For example, this is a typical List that I return as a ReadOnlyCollection:

```
    private readonly List<string> _encryptionKeys;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> EncryptionKeys => _encryptionKeys.AsReadOnly();
```

================================================

However, this is the convulation I need to do for a ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>:

```
    private readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>> _attributes;
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>> Attributes => _attributes;
```

... using a temporary variable:

```
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> attributes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

... to which I add values and its lists, I then build my property:

```
        Dictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>> readonlyListDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>();
        foreach (string key in attributes.Keys)
            readonlyListDictionary.Add(key, attributes[key].AsReadOnly());
        _attributes = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>(readonlyListDictionary);
```

================================================

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend avoiding `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` for various reasons I won't go into. Consider returning `IReadOnly...` interfaces instead. Also look at `System.Collections.Immutable` (as Immutability offers greater guarantees to consumers than simply `IReadOnly...`).

Comment: Do you need random access to the values in the lists? You could instead just create a lookup out of the dictionary and it is effectively a readonly dictionary of enumerables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an extension method, then you don't have to think about it the whole time:

```cs
public static ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>> AsReadOnly<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> source)
{
    return new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>(
        new Dictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>(
        source.Select(kvp =>
            new KeyValuePair<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.AsReadOnly())
    ));
}
```

Although, the constructor that takes `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` is only available in .NET 5. So in earlier versions we would have to `foreach`. This option may also be more performant as we pre-size the dictionary

```cs
public static ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>> AsReadOnly<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> source)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>(source.Count);
    foreach (var kvp in source)
        dict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.AsReadOnly();
    return new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, ReadOnlyCollection<TValue>>(dict);
}
```

Just use it like you use the other `AsReadOnly` extension.

Comment: That's beautiful! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Linq can do the heavylifting for you.

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> input = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>> output = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>(dict.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.AsReadOnly()));
```